# SqlCommand Parameter - must declare the scalar variable "@positionX".'

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I know there are a ton of question for this problem. Maybe is useless to ask again but after trying a lot I was unable to find a solution so I will be very grateful If someone helps me. The code is shown below:

```
String personQuery =
    "INSERT INTO Person(X, Y, Width, Height, Confidence) VALUES (@positionX, @positionY, @width, @height, @confidence)";

SqlCommand personCmd = new SqlCommand(personQuery, connection);

foreach (var objectItem in items)
{
    if (objectItem.Type == "person")
    {

          personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positionX", objectItem.X);
          personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positionY", objectItem.Y);
          personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@width", objectItem.Width);
          personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", objectItem.Height);
          personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confidence", objectItem.Confidence);
          personCmd.Parameters.Clear();

          connection.Open();
          personCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          connection.Close();

    }
}
```

After running this code I got this error: **Must declare the scalar variable "@positionX".'**
What is the problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are you adding parameters **and then clearing them**? `personCmd.Parameters.Clear();`

Comment: So you go to the trouble of setting up all of your parameters, *then* clear the parameter collection? You were probably trying to fix the problem that setting up the parameters in a loop caused the same parameter to be declared multiple times, but you've got the clear/populate the wrong way around. (Of course, better would be to declare the parameters outside the loop and just *set* them inside)

Comment: I want to insert to database multiple data. X, Y, Width, Height, Confidence parameters will be different for every person detected in the image. That's why I want to clear them every time...

Comment: How else do you want us to explain this to you? You're doing "Add, Clear, Execute", which doesn't work because "Execute" needs to use the work done by "Add".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: After opening and closing connection outside the loop and calling personCmd.Parameters.Clear(); after personCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); my code worked. Thank you for the help. I feel bad making this mistake: Set values, Clear Values, Execute values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the issue with erroneously calling `Clear` on your parameters before needing them for execution, there are a number of improvements to be made in your code.

- There's no need to keep redeclaring and clearing parameters in the loop. You can declare the command and parameters once, and then re-assign the values each iteration of the loop
- Instead of checking the item Type inside the loop, rather filter out any unwanted items before you iterate the `foreach`.
- Since command and connection are `IDisposable`, scoping commands and connections inside a `using` statement will guarantee release of resources ASAP for any code path, including an exception.
- Since this code is I/O intensive, if possible, switch the code to `async` to ease threadpool usage. There's `Async` versions of all the ADO.Net methods (i.e. `OpenAsync`, `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, etc which can be `await`ed)

```
const string personQuery = "INSERT INTO Person(X, Y, Width, Height, Confidence) " +
                           "VALUES (@positionX, @positionY, @width, @height, @confidence)";

// Define a long lived connection and command. Both are Disposable.
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
using (var personCmd = new SqlCommand(personQuery, connection))
{
    // Open the connection just the once
    connection.Open();

    // Define the command parameters without assigning them yet
    // Check the data types against your Sql schema ...
    personCmd.Parameters.Add("@positionX", SqlDbType.Int);
    personCmd.Parameters.Add("@positionY", SqlDbType.Int);
    ... etc other parameters

    // Filter the objects before you loop them. 
    // Better would be .Where(i => i is Person) if you have subclasses
    foreach (var objectItem in items.Where(i => i.Type == "person")) 
    {
        personCmd["@positionX"].Value = objectItem.X;
        personCmd["@positionY"].Value = objectItem.Y;
        ... assign other params
        personCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} // personCmd and connection will be automatically closed
```

Comment: Presumably you meant to change the second `AddWithValue` to `Add` as well, and may wish to link to [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed, thanks. Agreed - the type inference of AWV is  unreliable.

Comment: Thank you @StuartLC

Answer (score 3):

After reviewing the code; the problem is here

```
personCmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

This line must be after the  personCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

This can be full code:

```
connection.Open();
    foreach (var objectItem in items)
    {
        personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positionX", objectItem.X);
        personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positionY", objectItem.Y);
        personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@width", objectItem.Width);
        personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", objectItem.Height);
        personCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confidence", objectItem.Confidence);
        personCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        personCmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Just make the personCmd.Parameters.Clear(); after  personCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: After opening and closing connection outside the loop, my code works. Thank you...